# jQuery .change() not responding as expected

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a `select` that I am trying to do a jQuery `.change` event on. For some reason it is not recognizing the `id` of the select. It is built through another `AJAX` call to a php file that creates the select and its options.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#unitselector").on('change', function()
        {
            console.log('made it');
            var unit=$('#unitselector').filter(':selected').val();
            var dataString = {unit:unit};
            console.log(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "classes/unit_info.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $('.unitinfo').html(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

relevant PHP:

```
    echo '<select id="unitselector" name="units">';
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $units[] = $row['unit_name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$row['unit_name'].'">'.$row['unit_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`It is built through another AJAX call to a php file that creates the select and its options.`

That means it's dynamically added to the DOM and as such requires event delegation. [jQuery 1.7+ uses the .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method in order to bind properly.

```
$("#unitselector").on('change', function()
```

to

```
$(document).on('change', '#unitselector', function()
```

Further, there's really no reason to try and get the value like you're doing. You're inside of the element and therefore can access it through `this` which is the native javascript object, or `$(this)` which is a jQuery object, either way will work fine.

```
var unit = $(this).val();
//or
var unit = this.value;
```